# Need to serve both GSPs and JSON from a Grails 3.1.5 app

Tags: json, rest, grails, gsp

I wanted my Grails 3.1.5 app to serve both JSON data using the *.gson format AND, for some pages/URLs I wanted to continue to use GSPs.

I built an app using the rest-api profile. 
Then I copied over controllers and views from an other app that I'd built using the web-api.

In doing so, and to be consistent, I also moved index.gson to a different location.

Now I get a:

```
Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
```

Started digging into the viewResolvers that are available in the 3.1.5 code base. It is possible that the rest-api profile configures a viewResolver to look for *.gson files in a certain location.

Is there anyway to configure maybe a CompositeViewResolver that looks for both the views, *.gson and *.gsps?

If so, how can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: When you build from the rest-api profile, part of that profile definition is the elimination of most of the UI support - API's typically don't render UI, so the profile drops support to reduce file size.  Might be less work if you start with a normal web app, and introduce the JSON responses/.gson format support for the API portions.

Answer (score 5):

I've managed to resolve this issue by adding this plugin to build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp'
```

and with both

```
profile 'org.grails.profiles:web'
profile 'org.grails.profiles:rest-api'
```

and apply plugins

```
apply plugin: 'org.grails.grails-web'
apply plugin: 'org.grails.grails-gsp'
apply plugin: 'org.grails.plugins.views-json'
```

Apparently, they remove it when you're using REST profile, to reduce overhead, as you rarely render HTML on REST service side.

Comment: Thanks, very useful, but since GRAILS 3.3 it is not enough, you need also `compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp:3.3.0.RC1"` in your build.gradle file instead of __org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp__ dependency, as it is said in [Official GRAILS documentation](https://gsp.grails.org/latest/guide/index.html#tagsAsMethodCalls).